# Vertical Scroll in Viewpager

Tags: android, scroll, android-viewpager

Here I have two files. I want to enable scrolling vertically in the viewpager. The content of the page exceeds the size of the page. Even though the content exceeds page size... I dont get a scroll. Plz help.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScrollView
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:fillViewport="true" 
      >
     <RelativeLayout    

     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <RelativeLayout      
      android:id="@+id/secAct1"
    android:layout_height="25dip"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        >
          <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/cn1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:text="cn"
        />
      <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/si1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:paddingRight="10dip"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
         android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="15sp"
         android:text="si"
        />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/secAct1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="30dip">
    <Button 
    android:id="@+id/submitAll"    
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
    android:text="Submit Responses"    
    />   
    <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/lp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"   
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:text="Thank you for your valuable responses!\n On submitting, you will not be able to changes your                            responses.\nYou responses will be uploaded when your device is connected to the internet.\nThank you for your     valuable responses!\n On submitting, you will not be able to changes your responses.\nYou responses will be uploaded when your device is connected to the internet.Thank you for your valuable responses!\n On submitting, you will not be able to changes your responses.\nYou responses will be uploaded when your device is connected to the internet.Thank you for your valuable responses!\n On submitting, you will not be able to changes your responses.\nYou responses will be uploaded when your device is connected to the internet.\nThank you for your valuable responses!\n On submitting, you will not be able to changes your responses.\nYou responses will be uploaded when your device is connected to the internet.Thank you for your valuable responses!\n On submitting, you will not be able to changes your responses.\nYou responses will be uploaded when your device is connected to the internet.Thank you for your valuable responses!\n On submitting, you will not be able to changes your responses.\nYou responses will be uploaded when your device is connected to the internet.\nThank you for your valuable responses!\n On submitting, you will not be able to changes your responses.\nYou responses will be uploaded when your device is connected to the internet.Thank you for your valuable responses!\n On submitting, you will not be able to changes your responses.\nYou responses will be uploaded when your device is connected to the internet.Thank you for your valuable responses!\n On submitting, you will not be able to changes your responses.\nYou responses will be uploaded when your device is connected to the internet.\nThank you for your valuable responses!\n On submitting, you will not be able to changes your responses.\nYou responses will be uploaded when your device is connected to the internet.Thank you for your valuable responses!\n On submitting, you will not be able to changes your responses.\nYou responses will be uploaded when your device is connected to the internet."
      >
         </TextView>


        </LinearLayout>
           </RelativeLayout></ScrollView>
```

next file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <LinearLayout 
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragQue"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
     >

     <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"

        android:background="@drawable/radialback"
        >
    <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
            android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/fQ_P"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/fQ_P" 
            android:background="@color/yellow"
            android:textColor="@color/textGray" 
             /> 
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager > 

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-DirectionalViewPager check this out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first you have it so that the textview is above the cn & si buttons, even though the buttons are at the bottom of the screen, it isn't working the way you want it to.

```
android:layout_above="@+id/secAct1"
//should be
android:layout_below="@+id/secAct1"
```

That will give you submit button and text view on top with cn & si buttons underneath and be scroll-able.
If you want the cn & si buttons on top, in the second relative layout, change

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
//to
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
```

As for the second file, I don't know if the viewpager has a default scroll or not, so you might just have to wrap it in a scrollview.

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea why your original code wasn't doing what you wanted it to. The only thing I can think of is that having the relative layout aligned to the bottom of the parent relative layout was causing the `android:layout_above="@+id/secAct1` to be set as above the parent layout. But that is just a guess.